# Define a value to EditText

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, password-protection, textwatcher

I'm trying to make an Activity with an EditText that can only accept a value that I defined programatically in advanced -kind off like a password, like a word or a code number- so that the user can't access the next Activity if he dosen't enter the right *password*.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make something like that ? Do I have to use a TextWatcher ? If yes, how ?

Thanks!

Comment: `android:digits="enter_your_characters_here"` in your xml layout should do what do you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this.

```
If (edittext.getText().toString()==myPreProgrammedString){
   start next activity
}
else{
   show warning wrong password
}
```

Usually you would put something like this in a onClick method of a login button. But I use something similar in textwatchers afterTextChanged method to check if the entered text is in a list and then enable the OK button.

BTW: hardcoding passwords in an app is never good practice.

Comment: Thank you, it works! If I may ask, how can I stock the password then ?

Comment: best way to let the user thinkup there own password, hash it and store it in something like firebase. With a hardcoded password every user has the same password and re-engineering your app gives unauthorized people the password . Like I said, not very safe.

Comment: Actually, what I'm making is a game, and before the Activity where the player enter the password, he is given hints about the right password. He have to guess it, so there is only one possible answer ! Kind off like when you're given a riddle and you try to guess the answer.

Comment: So not really a security risk and only cheaters would hack the app. A hardcoded string is acceptable then.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression(regex) to define your password format. An example of a regex password:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\S+$).{8,}$
^                 # start-of-string
(?=.*[0-9])       # a digit must occur at least once
(?=.*[a-z])       # a lower case letter must occur at least once
(?=.*[A-Z])       # an upper case letter must occur at least once
(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])  # a special character must occur at least once
(?=\S+$)          # no whitespace allowed in the entire string
.{8,}             # anything, at least eight places though
$ 

            # end-of-string
```

Add TextWatch to your EditText to observe your text change when you type in it

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               Pattern PASSWORD_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("Your pattern");

                if (PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(s.toString()).matches()) { 
                    //Password is valid, move to new activity
                }
            }
        });
```

It's simple with regex bro!

Comment: I don't think Emma is a bro :).